# Ordering member for async and method in Typescript-ESLint

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Is there a way for ordering async / sync method member ?

example

```js
# ❌ Incorrect
function myFunction() {
  // something code
}

async function myAsyncFunction() {
  // something code
}
```

```js
# ✅ correct
async function myFunction() {
  // something code
}

function myAsyncFunction() {
  // something code
}
```

Why ?

I think using async function can be indicated that communicates, affects to other component with return values OR sends as integration activities.

so we can expect async would be have bindings to data flows more than sync.

Thus async function is more important than syncs.

Comment: I don't understand the question the way it is currently written. Your two code examples are identical except for the Incorrect/Correct comment at the top.

Comment: oh, sorry, it is my mistakes. I would modify my post @y2bd

Comment: @Evert Thank you your commend. bit I already have applied that rules and there is no about async ordering. Maybe I should create new order rules hmm

Comment: @Evert But they don't provide how can I customize that rules. That contents and eslint rules has no any about async or promised function ordering

Comment: @Evert hmm.. you mean I should write the rules as plugin then attach to eslint right ?